# MySQL Join Condition

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm having trouble thinking of a way to do the following join in MySQL. I'm not sure which joins would be best suited for this task, so I'll edit the title when someone points it out. Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do.

I have two tables, call one `Students`, and the other `Marks`.
They are setup as follows,

## Students

Only the Id field is unique

```
  .----+-----------------+--------+--------.
  | Id | Name            | Parent |  Mark  |
  +----+-----------------+--------+--------+
  |  1 | Name goes here1 |     0  |     0  |
  |  2 | Name goes here2 |     0  |    20  |
  |  3 | Name goes here3 |     2  |    45  |
  |  4 | Name goes here4 |     2  |    50  |
  |  5 | Name goes here3 |     1  |    20  |
  |  6 | Name goes here1 |     0  |    65  |
  .----+-----------------+--------+--------.
```

## Marks

Id and Name are unique

```
  .----+-----------------+--------.
  | Id | Name            |Ranking |
  +----+-----------------+--------+
  |  1 | Name goes here1 |    20  |
  |  2 | Name goes here2 |    60  |
  |  3 | Name goes here3 |    90  |
  |  4 | Name goes here4 |   200  |
  |  5 | Name goes here5 |    45  |
  |  6 | Name goes here6 |    76  |
  .----+-----------------+--------.
```

Now, what I need is as follows.
 1. I need to join Students on itself so that `Students`.`Parent`=`Students`.`Id`
 2. In the above join I only want to select the row where `Students`.`Mark` (S2) is the highest under that parent. Also, only join if `Students`.`Mark` >= 20 (Also S2).
 3. I want to join the previous `Student`.`Name` on `Marks`.`Name` (From S1), selecting the Ranking.

## Result

```
  .----+-----------------+--------+--------+--------+----------.
  | Id | Name            | Parent |  Child |  Mark  |  Ranking |
  +----+-----------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
  |  1 | Name goes here1 |     0  |     5  |   20   |     20   |
  |  2 | Name goes here2 |     0  |     4  |   50   |     60   |
  .----+-----------------+--------+--------+--------+----------.
```

I think(?) this is possible using one query, but am not certain.

Comment: I had a look at this but it's too confusing - why have you got the name in the marks table as well? Why is the mark in the students table? It looks really badly normalised, but this may be just the result of your obfuscating the original names I guess. But it's too abstract to help you with, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, the normalization seems a bit off, but to be fair the actual table is *far* more complex. It's a complicated question in any form, and I can't reduce it much more without removing all validity from the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query should do what you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
    s1.Id, s1.Name, s1.Parent, s2.Id as Child, MAX(s2.Mark) as Mark, m.Ranking 

FROM 
    Students s1
    INNER JOIN Students s2 ON (s1.id = s2.parent AND s2.Mark >= 20) 
    LEFT JOIN Marks m ON (s1.name = m.name) 

GROUP BY 
    s1.Id, s1.Name, s1.Parent, Child, Ranking;
```

Comment: It's not really child/parents at all. I obfuscated the database to keep the question generalized. It happened to be the first thing that came to mind, in any case it's not the relationship the important but rather the method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it was obfuscated. I removed the additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
select * from Students S1
join Students S2 on(S1.Id=S2.StudentId)
```

2.

You need to clarify which of the two instances of Students you mean here in each of the two cases -- S1 or S2? As you express your (homework?) assignment, it's 100% ambiguous in each case. Could be `where S1.Mark>=20 and S1.Mark=(select max(s3.mark) from students s3` etc etc, or many other variations.

3. again the ambiguity about what instance of Students you mean, anyway you just need to alter the select and add one join:

   select Marks.Ranking from
        Students S1
   join Students S2 on(S1.Id=S2.StudentId)
   join Marks on(S1.Name=Marks.Name)

and the `where` clause as before.

Comment: To clarify, it's not an assignment, I just want to keep the actual database ambiguous. For 2., both come from S2. Then for 3., join on S1.Name. I thought it was somewhat(?) clear based on the result, but I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Never do a cross join... (thats a join with no specified inner/outer/left/right)

Comment: @corymathews, "cross join" does NOT mean "omission of the adjective" (standard SQL and MySQL allow the explicit adjective CROSS, too): it means _omission of the ON clause_. JOIN...ON means INNER JOIN (go downvote the wikipedia page on SQL: it gives exactly this perfectly acceptable and correct syntax as the first example of JOIN!-).